# Create pyspark column from large # of case statements w/ regex

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to transform a complicated text field into one of ~2000 possible values based on regular expressions and conditions.

Example: if VAL1 in ('3025','4817') and re.match('foo', VAL2) then (123, "GROUP_ABX")
elif ... (repeat about 2000 unique scenarios)

I put this bunch of conditions into a massive pySpark UDF function.  Problem is, if I have more than a few hundred conditions, the performance grinds to a halt.

The UDF is registered like so:

```
schema = StructType([
            StructField("FOO_ID", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("FOO_NAME", StringType(), False)])
    spark.udf.register("FOOTagging", FOOTag, schema)
    test_udf = udf(FOOTag, schema)
```

the dataframe is updated like:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv(file)\
      .toDF(*Fields)\
      .select(*FieldList)\
      .withColumn("FOO_TAG_STRUCT", test_udf('VAL1','VAL2'))
```

When I run with <200 conditions, I process the 23k row file in a couple seconds.  When I get over 500 or so, it takes forever.

Seems UDF doesn't handle large functions.  Is there another solution out there?

Comment: if you already had it typed into UDF than why not just let it run inside select as plain select()? Why did  you need to create udf for that? Or did you tried to use python regexes on spark? if that than rewriting it into spark regexes could help out..

Comment: Thank you.  As an update:
Writing as a 2k row when...otherwise statement doesn't work -- either leads to a recursion error in python or it exceeds the java function size boundary.
What worked: I put the 2k matching patterns in a broadcast variable and had my UDF use 'find' to get the first match.